# What's the best way to record Neo4j queries?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have Neo4j instances in several remote geographical locations, working with local data. I also have a master Neo4j instance which will store data from all locations. In case of network failure I want the remote instances to save queries  which can be replayed later at the master instance. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm using Neo4j .Net client

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Neo4j Enterprise with the High Availibility mode ? In that case the slaves are writing automatically first to the master.

Otherwise you can log the full requests (meaning the cypher query + parameters)

Make sure to activate the http logging in the neo4j-server.properties configuration file :

```
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

And in your neo4j-http-logging.xml you can add this pattern in your appenders :

```
<pattern>%fullRequest\n\n%</pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some undocumented logging options (experimental):

```
dbms.querylog.enabled=true
# in ms
dbms.querylog.threshold=500
dbms.querylog.path=data/log/queries.log
```